# Rocket.chat notification configuration

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications, rocket.chat, react-native-notifications

I'm white labeling rocket.chat react native application. Everything else is up and running except the notifications. Following are the issues I'm facing.

1. Android: Firebase configuration is completed and rocket.chat app is receiving test notification from firebase but when a test notification is triggered from rocket chat admin panel, it doesn't work.
2. IOS: IOS is not receiving notification from either sides i.e firebase or rocket.chat.

Please do let me know if any further information is required.
Thanks.

I tried configuring firebase and followed all the steps provided in rocket.chat whitelabel docs but unable to get notifications running.